# IconImageInfo is not abstract and does not override abstract method getExtras() in HasImageMetadata

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

I am facing this error while trying to run the project from android studio.

Error:

> IconImageInfo is not abstract and does not override abstract method getExtras() in HasImageMetadata
> private static class IconImageInfo implements ImageInfo {

Thanks in advance

Before that I was facing the Gradlew sync issue to resolve I've upgrade the gradlew version in
gradlew.warpper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
npm i @react-native-community/toolbar-android@^0.2.1
```